# Perl Readline on closed filehandle - file does not exist error

Tags: perl, file, directory, readline

I am working on a simple perl program for my first assignment in my programming class.  I literally have been stuck on this first part for more than a day.  I cannot get my program to simply open a text file that is in the same directory as the program.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my($fileName, $line);

print "Please enter name of file to be opened: ", "\n";
$fileName = <STDIN>;
chop($fileName);

#Associates FILE filehandle with the file: "filename.txt"
open(FILE, $fileName) or die("Can't open '$fileName': $!");

while(my $line = <FILE>){
    print $line;
}
```

I am using strawberry perl.  To run the program I am dragging and dropping the program into the command line to get the address of the program.  It then attempts to run it.

It initially gave me a readline on closed filehandle error, and then I included the or die("Can't open '$fileName': $!"); portion of the code.

Now it says that there is no such file at the directory, but I know that the test.txt file is there because I just created it.

Picture of the code results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlK5g.jpg

File directory that shows locations of my files: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3FSK.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure you're in the right directory?  `use Cwd; print getcwd(), "\n";`  (Or just enter [`echo %cd% |`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/921762/132382) or `dir |` as your filename — but you should really use the [three-argument form of `open()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) with an explicit MODE to prevent that kind of trick.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prompt is showing `C:\Users\jacjar\Documents` as the current working directory

So this is where the program will look for `test.txt`

But it is not in that directory

`text.txt` is in `L:\College\Junior Year\1st Semester\COSC 320 (Programming Languages)`

Move your `test.txt` file to the C: path shown above and it will work

Comment: to change the working directory in the cmd shell, use the cd command.  To change the working directory in a perl script, use [chdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html)

Comment: Yeah, that's a unfortunately "feature" of Windows. It can be disabled, though. "Tools" | "Folder Options" | "View" | Uncheck "Hide Extensions for known file types" | "Apply" | "Apply to Folders"

Answer (score 1):

Do you realize you are trying to open `C:\User\jacjar\Documents\test.txt`?